# In Java can you use getter and setters in a parameterized manner i.e pass in a code to decide which class variable to return

Tags: java, switch-statement, setter, getter

I'm working on a project that requires me to have three specific ticket types that have certain properties.

Some of these properties are final and static as they should not change, however further types could be required. This would mean changes to the abstract class but not the class implementing it. I have created an abstract class that contains these class variables in order to limit the logic I need to write in the class implements the values. I have written getter methods that receive a parameter (a ticket type code) and then the method switches the code and returns the appropriate value. In the setter methods I receive a code parameter and then update the class variable dependent on the code received.

My questions are:

1.Is this bad practice if so should I revise the design of my class? 
 2. And if so, how should I approach the problem in a way that I could make the code reusable and parameter driven?

Previously I would have created an xml or parameter file so I could change the parameter file instead of making code changes but I have not coded in Java for a few years and I am still learning the best practices.

Here is a code snippet:

```
private static final int iPickThreeLimit = 50;
private static final int iPickFourLimit = 40;
private static final int iPickFiveLimit = 60;

private static int iPickThreeCount = 50;
private static int iPickFourCount = 40;
private static int iPickFiveCount = 60;

protected static void setTicketCount(String sTicketType) {

    switch (sTicketType) {
    case "PickThree":
        AbstractLotteryMachine.iPickThreeCount = iPickThreeCount--;
        break;
    case "PickFour":
        AbstractLotteryMachine.iPickFourCount = iPickFourCount--;
        break;
    case "PickFive":
        AbstractLotteryMachine.iPickFiveCount = iPickFiveCount--;
        break;
    } //end switch
} // end setTicketCount

protected static int getPickLimit(String sTicketType) {
    int iTicketLimit = 0;

    switch (sTicketType) {
    case "PickThree":
        iTicketLimit = iPickThreeLimit;
        break;
    case "PickFour":
        iTicketLimit = iPickFourLimit;
        break;
    case "PickFive":
        iTicketLimit = iPickFiveLimit;
        break;
    } //end switch
    return iTicketLimit;

  } //end getPickLimit
```

If I have to write an individual getter and setter method for each ticket type this balloons the logic required in the class I am implementing this abstract class in.

Comment: why not use an immutable class, with static factory methods for each type?

Comment: A switch like that is most often a bad idea. You use polymorphism to have each specific subclass decide what should happen. So override methods, instead of doing a type based switch in the base class.

Comment: @GhostCat In this case override methods won't work because the signature is identical?

Comment: Not overloading. Overriding. Same signature. Different behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest looking into an enum variable; they operate as static and can contain values.

```
public enum Pick
{
  PickThree(30),
  PickFour(40),
  PickFive(50);

  private int limit;

  private Pick(int i) { limit = i; }

  public int getLimit() { return limit; }
}
```

Now your other class(es) can have a `Pick` type variable that can hold any one of these, and use that variable/class' `getLimit()` method to get the number. The enum type can have other logic in it as well, this just covers what you have in your question.

Comment: That is really just a comment.

Comment: That still requires me to pass in the limit I want? I need to be able to get any value based on the code so I don't have to write hard coded logic for each type. Also this does not cater for the class variable that needs to be decremented.

Comment: The only place you are "passing in a limit" is in the constructor of the specific enum; this is the equivalent of the "private static int" statements you have setting the limit. You do not pass in the limit you want (getLimit has no parameters); I thought this was a "type of ticket". Once you set your "Pick" variable to the correct type, say to a variable named "pickType", then you can use "pickType.getLimit()" to get the hard-coded number. If the number needs to be stored somewhere so it can be decremented under some condition or other, I would expect that to be handled elsewhere.

Comment: I made a correction to the source -- the enum declaration should not have "static" in it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the immutable approach is a lot more cleaner.

```
public final class Ticket {

   private final int pickCount;
   private int pickThreeLimit=50;

   private Ticket(int count, int limit){
      this.count = count;
      this.limit = limit
   }

   pubic int getTicketLimit(){
      return this.pickThreeLimit;
   }

   public in getTicketCount(){
      return this.count;
   }

   //add more static methods for each ticket type
   public static Ticket createPickThree(){
     this.pickThreeLimit--;
     return new Ticket(50,pickThreeLimit);
   }
}
```